# I need to pass column names using variable in select statement in Store Procedure but i cannot use dynamic query

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

Here is my SQL query below. I want to select values from the column names given as variables. Is there any appropriate way of doing this except using a dynamic query?

```
SELECT EPV.EmployeeCode, @RateOfEmployee, @RateOfEmployer
FROM [HR_EmployeeProvisions] EPV
```

Comment: mysql or sql-server?

Answer (score 5):

One way to do this without using dynamic sql is using CASE statement

But this is ugly

```
SELECT EPV.EmployeeCode, case @RateOfEmployee  when 'RateOfEmployee' then RateOfEmployee
when 'X' then X 
..
end , case @RateOfEmployer  when 'RateOfEmployer' then RateOfEmployer
when 'Y' then Y
..
end 
FROM [HR_EmployeeProvisions] EPV
```

You have to check all the column's in `CASE` statement.

Comment: I have tried this already but it didn't work for me. Also it makes the query quite lengthy by adding case statements for each column. Thank you for your answer. :)

Comment: I have tried that already but i am using UNION ALL for couple of other statements so i couldn't add this in my scenario. I am already using this CASE statement in my query. :)

Answer (score 5):

You can't parameterize [identifiers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175874.aspx) in Sql server, and I doubt it's possible in any other relational database.

Your best choice is to use dynamic Sql.

Note that dynamic sql is very often a security hazard and you must defend your code from [sql injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

I would probably do something like this:

```
Declare @Sql nvarchar(500)
Declare numberOfColumns int;

select @numberOfColumns = count(1)
from information_schema.columns
where table_name = 'HR_EmployeeProvisions'
and column_name IN(@RateOfEmployee, @RateOfEmployer)

if @numberOfColumns = 2 begin

Select @Sql = 'SELECT EmployeeCode, '+ QUOTENAME(@RateOfEmployee) +' ,'+ QUOTENAME(@RateOfEmployer) +
'FROM HR_EmployeeProvisions'

exec(@Sql)
end
```

This way you make sure that the column names actually exists in the table, as well as using [`QUOTENAME`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176114.aspx) as another layer of safety.

Note: in your presentation layer you should handle the option that the select will not be performed since the column names are invalid.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but unfortunately i cannot use this.

Comment: @Prdp actually I think your answer is equally good when there are not many columns.  If the table have many columns it will be too cumbersome .

Comment: @MuhammadBilal why not?

Comment: @MuhammadBilal - Start explaining your problem instead of just saying *I cannot use/ It didn't work*

Comment: @Prdp I have explored it enough. My scenario doesn't allow me to use dynamic query may be something related to PIVOT will be helpful. I appreciate your answer but unfortunately this is not something i was looking for.

Comment: @MuhammadBilal Prdp's answer doesn't involve dynamic sql.

Comment: @ZoharPeled exec(@Sql) : this statement declares that a dynamic query is being executed. How can you say that it doesn't contain a dynamic query when it consists of.

Comment: @MuhammadBilal Please read my last comment more carefully, I was refering to Prdp's answer, not my own answer.

Comment: @ZoharPeled oh sorry my bad. I have tried that already but i am using UNION ALL for couple of other statements so i couldn't add this in my scenario. I am already using this CASE statement in my query. :)

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [UNPIVOT](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) clause - I'm not sure it is applicable for your case but in some circumstances it can be used to query a value by the column name without dynamic SQL:

```
create table t1 (
  a int,
  b int,
  c int
);

insert into t1 values
(1, 11, 111),
(2, 22, 222),
(3, 33, 333);

select a, col_name, col_value from t1
unpivot (col_value for col_name in (b, c)) as dt;
```

Result:

```
| a | col_name | col_value |
|---|----------|-----------|
| 1 |        b |        11 |
| 1 |        c |       111 |
| 2 |        b |        22 |
| 2 |        c |       222 |
| 3 |        b |        33 |
| 3 |        c |       333 |
```

([SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d8bde/6))

If you only need a value in `a` depending on some condition on (dynamically) either `b` or `c`, you can build the condition on that. If you need either values in column `b` or `c`, you can add `... WHERE col_name = ?`. If you need more columns, you'd probably need to filter the column values on the un-pivoted table than pivot it again to get the values back in columns.

Comment: can you show an example of how unpivot can help in this case?

Comment: I see what you mean now. nice.