# Dynamic Query: values and number of attributes determined by user

Tags: java, mysql, database, database-design, dynamic-sql

I'm developing a java system that conducts statistics on the system's database (mysql database) based on the attributes selected by the user during run time.
For example, this query:

```
select count(*)
from diseases
where bloodtype = 'A+' & age BETWEEN 10 AND 20 & disease = 'coma'
```

where the "where" clause is determined at run time, due to that I thought of using the dynamic SQL, so the query might look something like this:

```
select count(*)
from diseases
where bloodtype = ? & age BETWEEN ? AND ? & disease = ?
```

but the problem is that in this system, not only the values of the (?) are determined at run time, but also the attributes in the where clause (eg: bloodtype, age and id, etc.).

I've searched the internet to find a way to write a dynamic SQL query that the number of attributes and their values are determined at run time by the user's input, but didn't find a thing. Can you please guide me?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not only providing data dynamically but also the columns to be queried, parametrized queries aren't a feasible solution.

You'll probably need to create the statement in Java and provide SQL Injection protection by yourself.

---

See [I need to pass column names using variable in select statement in Store Procedure but i cannot use dynamic query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36419576/i-need-to-pass-column-names-using-variable-in-select-statement-in-store-procedur) for some thought on how this can be handled without using dynamic SQL (or queries created using Java string manipulation) - but all of them will probably be sub-optimal for your use case.

Comment: I thought of writing the dynamic query like this:

    select count(*)
    from diseases
    where bloodtype = ? & age BETWEEN ? AND ? & disease = ? & id = ? & nationallity = ? & (rest of the database attributes = ?)

and pass the values for what the user choose, and place empty single quotes for the non-choosen fields. (eg: id = '' )

Comment: @Ciba -- `''` would imply checking for the empty string; this is probably not what he wants.

Comment: I build `WHERE` clauses dynamically all the time in PHP.  Build an array of `key = 'value`` and `AND` them together.  Be sure to properly escape each `value`.

Comment: @RickJames Thank you so much. But sorry, not sure what you meant by "Build an array of key = 'value`` and AND` them together.". Does this mean that I should build an array that contains the names of the database's attributes, each one is initialized by the string 'value', and when a user chooses an attribute, its value in the array will be assigned another value different from 'value'? If possible can you please show me part of a code to get a better understanding +  how can I ensure escaping each 'value'?

Answer (score 0):

Construct the `WHERE` clause in Java using string functions.  Then, to substitute (and escape) the parameters, see [Setting CallableStatement input parameters](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-usagenotes-statements-callable.html).

Sorry, I have to leave you there; I haven't touched Java in 17 years, so I am bound to be rusty.

Answer (score 0):

Are you allowed to use JPA or a framework like Hibernate? Then criteria queries may be an elegant solution for your problem.

The attributes are not arbitrary strings, but must match the properties of the table(s) used in the query.

So if, for each attribute to be used in the select clause, you define a predicate like

```
Predicate p = builder.equal(attributeName, inputValue);
```

you can dynamically enrich your query with all the predicates the user chose using

```
query.where(p)
```

There is more about this topic, e.g. to create typesafe queries, cf. http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-typesafejpa/ or http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjitv.html.

Building SQL queries as strings in the application invites to SQL injection attacks and should be avoided.