# How to we prevent SQL Injection by Regular Expression or any other way in asp.net

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-injection

Before I ask - I do know about stored procedure is best way to prevent sql injection. We can achieve by parameterized stored procedure.

But in my application I am using dynamic queries as well in stored procedure where sql injection is possible.

Please suggest me a way to stop sql injection like any regular expression or some other way.
Example :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[USP_BusinessSearch]
    @Product INT = NULL, 
    @BusinessName VARCHAR(100) = NULL

    AS

    DECLARE @AdditionalCriteria AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @BaseQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

    BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON  
    SET @BaseQuery = 'Select * FROM Business WHERE ProductID = ' + @Product
    SET @AdditionalCriteria = ' AND BusinessName = '+@BusinessName+' '

    SET @BaseQuery = @BaseQuery + @AdditionalCriteria

    EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @BaseQuery

    END
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can parametrise dynamic statements too. Without seeing the problem code though, how can we help you make it secure?

Comment: Where is an example of your "dynamic queries"? What has to do your question with "regular expressions" ?

Comment: Yea, it's the *parameters* that really matter for preventing injection. Not whether they're being used by a stored proc or other query. If you need to parameterise unparameterizable items (e.g. table or column names) then use *whitelisting* of acceptable values.

Comment: @Larnu I don't want to use parametrise statement. I want to know a front end validation like regular expression or any jquery/javascript plugin

Comment: Now my question is: Why do you need to transform a simple query like `Select * FROM Business WHERE ProductID = @Product AND BusinessName = @BusinessName` in a dynamic sql?

Comment: You may want to read Erland Sommarskog's [Dynamic Search Conditions in T-SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2008.html) before deciding that dynamic SQL is the right approach here.

Comment: @Steve its just an example how can we construct dynamic query, actual I have more than 1000 lines in my stored procedure and I think its not a good way to write down all 1000 lines here

Comment: That query in no way needs to be dynamic. That can easily be replaced with simply `Select * FROM Business WHERE ProductID =  @Product AND BusinessName = @BusinessName;` Also, note that `'...ProductID = ' + @Product` would fail as `@Product` is an `int`, and `'Select * FROM Business WHERE ProductID = '` **cannot** be converted to a `int`. We are far from having the full/real picture here.

Answer (score 3):

I truly hope that the procedure you've posted is not one you are using in a production environment, because it is not safe at all. The fact that you are using parameters does not mean you are safe from SQL Injection - it's how you use the parameters. This procedure can be written without dynamic SQL which would make it safe from SQL injection like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[USP_BusinessSearch]
    @Product INT = NULL, 
    @BusinessName VARCHAR(100) = NULL

AS

SELECT * 
FROM Business 
WHERE ProductID = @Product
AND BusinessName = @BusinessName
```

Please note that this doesn't mean that any dynamic SQL approach is vulnerable to SQL Injection - it's quite possible to prevent SQL Injection using dynamic SQL if needed:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[USP_BusinessSearch]
    @Product INT = NULL, 
    @BusinessName VARCHAR(100) = NULL

AS

DECLARE @ParamDefinition AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @BaseQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT  @BaseQuery = N'Select * FROM Business WHERE ProductID = @Product AND BusinessName = @BusinessName',
        @ParamDefinition = N'@Product INT, @BusinessName VARCHAR(100)'  

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @BaseQuery, @ParamDefinition, @Product, @BusinessName

END
```

The key difference between this approach and the procedure in the question is that the query in the question simply concatenates the parameter values into the dynamic SQL, thus making it vulnerable to SQL Injection, whereas the procedures in the answers use the parameters the way they are intended to be used - as parameters.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thanks!

Comment: @ZoharPeled Thanks for your response, it will be helpful to me, but I want know some front end validation to stop sql injection like a jquery validation or a regular expression.

Comment: Sanitizing input is not a full-proof way to prevent SQL Injection. Parameters are (well, at least when used correctly). If you find a need to query unknown tables or columns (which can't be parameterized), you can white-list and `QUOTENAME` them like shown in [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36419620/3094533)